# Linq Query very slow

Tags: wpf, linq, sqlite

```
 var data= (from a in context.Table1
              where a.Id== id
              select a);
  return data.ToList();
```

I have the above linq query in wpf project . The above query fetches about 0.2-0.3 million rows from SQLite database. The result fetching is fast but the while doing data.ToList(), it takes lots of time because of the no. of rows and hence my UI waits for 15-20 seconds to see the result. How should I proceed to solve this issue.

Also, if the above table contains foreign keys then while accessing the child element, it throws ObjectDisposeedException. I guess its due to lazy loading, so I tried to set the child elements explicitly. It worked but then my process got even more slower

Comment: Please tell us how you use the data afterwards. Do you bind them do a cotnro? What type of cotnrol? thanks

Comment: One case is where I need to show all the data in a chart, other case is like taking averages etc. I do not bind it to a control, I do some calculations and that calculated result is binded to basic controls like textblocks etc.

Comment: How do you show the data to the chart? Do you set as datasource of the chart the result of your query? Please post us also this part of code. It crucial to see how the binding happens, in order to avoid the .ToList() of the query, if that's possible at all.

Comment: yes and about averages etc. should I do it in the query rather than fetching the whole rows

Comment: As far as the calculation of the averages, you can do it without casting your result to List. Post exactly what's the porperty of a  you want its average value and I post the corresponding code.

Comment: Thanks, Christos, without casting it to list will solve my problem, will try it, if the problem still persists, I will post the code

Answer (score 2):

Of course the `LINQ` command "executes" in no time, below is just represents the query.

```
 var data= (from a in context.Table1
              where a.Id== id
              select a);
```

The query is only executed once you iterate over it as `return data.ToList();` which is exactly what the `ToList` method does.

I would advise you to use the `Skip` and `Take` operators in your pagers to narrow down the result queried from the database. Doing this, you only request the 10 or 20 elements or whatever you need, resulting in a much smoother experience.

Doing pagination will surely optimize your retrieval performance also..

Comment: Agree. Don't put 0.3 millions of rows in UI. Paginate it.

Comment: The thing is there is no pagination,for eg: lets say I want to show all the data in a chart, so I need all the data in one go,so how should I proceed to get a smooth experience?

Comment: @yshooooo  what type of chart control you are using??? you didn't mentioned it in your question..Please be mentioned all information possible, because this will definitely help us to give you a proper, productive answer .

Answer (score 0):

Before you use the ".ToList()" means that the code you are still in mode "IQueryable", and when using ".ToList()" means you access the physical database.
You can take some of the data in a way ".Take(x)" and ".Page(y)" on LINQ. You can try this method:

```
int page = 1;
int size = 10
var customers = tx.Customers
               .Where(x => x.....)
               .Skip((page - 1) * 10).Take(size)
               .ToList();
```